# NodeJS routing to 404 instead of correct page

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code. I am trying to get it to show the users in my db when I go to http://localhost:4000/user, however all I get is 404. I would appreciate some help as I'm clearly not understanding something.

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var user = require('./routes/users');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();


//This is all setup code.
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/user',user);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

//Mongo code
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db1')
  .then(() =>  console.log('Connected to db succesfully'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));




module.exports = app;

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 4000!')
})
```

routes/user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userModel = require('../models/users.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/user', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("get request made");
});


router.route('/user')

  .get(function(req, res) {
        User.find(function(err, bears) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(bears);
        });
    });

    .post(function(req, res) {

            var user = new User();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
            user.firstNamename = req.body.firstName;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)
        user.lastName=req.body.lastName;
        user.email=req.body.email;

            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

            console.log("User created");
            });


        })

module.exports = router;
```

model/users.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create a user schema
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: you need to use the express.router()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems here:

- first you've required `./routes/users` but your route file is `user.js`, so it should be:

  ```
  var user = require('./routes/user');
  ```

---

- second, when you have mounted user middleware on your app you choose to prepend `/user` to all of user routes(`app.use('/user', user);`); so when you say:

  ```
  router.route('/user').get(function ...
  ```

  it responds to `/user/user` routes. so the right implementation is:

  ```
  router.route('/').get(function ...
  ```

  this responds to `/user`

  ---
- third, semicolon before your `post` request should be removed.

  **Note** that `router.route('/').get(function...` is exactly the same as `router.get('/', function ...` . we use first pattern for chaining different http verbs to one route. but *semicolon* destroyed the linking:

  ```
  router
    .route('/')
      .get(function ...)
      .post(function ...)
      .delete(function ...);
  ```

Comment: This helped me out alot, I was struggling to understand the routing. Thank you!